# Google Sheets: Using ImportXML to get text out of span

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import the floor price from that website into my Google Sheet:
https://digitaleyes.market/collections/Turtles

So for example right now the number "22"

I tried the following but with no success:

> =importxml("https://digitaleyes.market/collections/Turtles";"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/span[1]/text()")

or

> =importxml("https://digitaleyes.market/collections/Turtles";"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/span[1]")

I only get #NV all the time.

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page is built in javascript on the client side and not on the server side, you will not be able to retrieve the data by the importxml / importhtml functions.

See here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: Oh sad... :( but thank you though!

Comment: For some websites, you can find a json inside the source. Unfortunately, that was not the case here.